# How to install KVM in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, usb-drive, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB flash disk and found this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key). However I am stuck at the part of the KVM. I am supposed to type this command at the terminal

```
sudo kvm /dev/sdb -cdrom ~/.cache/testdrive/iso/ubuntu_natty-desktop-i386.iso
```

I tried installing kvm using `sudo apt-get install kvm`

However on running the command to install ubuntu, I get the following message.

```
`open /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
Could not initialize KVM, will disable KVM support
```

I also get this a QEMU terminal

```
Starting SeaBIOS (version 0.5.1)
Booting from hard disk....
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
Boot from floppy ....
Boot failed: could not read the boot disk
Booting from CD-Rom....
23MB medium detected
Boot failed: Could not read from CDROM (code 000c)
No bootable device
```

On running the command,

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

I get an output 0. This means that my computer does not support hardware virtualization.

**Computer Specs**

Intel Core 2 Duo 1.83 Ghz, 2 GB Ram, Intel Graphics Card

*Please help. I'll update the question as I get more info.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does your CPU support KVM ? What is the output of:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

0 = that your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization.

1, or more, your CPU supports hardware virtualization, but you still need to make sure that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

Please update your question to indicate the output of those commands, what CPU you have, and what manufacturer (so we might be able to help with bios).

Update: Fixed my typo and I see you updated your question as well. The output ( 0 ) indicates you do not have the hardware for KVM (sorry), I would suggest you try Virtualbox.

If you run kvm without the hardware capabilities, it will fall back to qemu, which will be slower then Virtualbox.

The error message you posted suggests the iso is corrupt, 23 Mb for an iso sounds too small, should be closer to 700 mg, try downloading the  iso again.

Comment: Shouldn't "1, or more, your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization, but you still need to make sure that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS." be "1, or more, your CPU **does** support hardware virtualization, but you still need to make sure that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS." ;)

Comment: do you know how to do it in the BIOS? Do I just enter the BIOS setting and look for hardware virtualization option? I know how to enter the BIOS setting.

Comment: @Nik You do not have the hardware. As you updated your question, so I updated my answer.